# How to sync edited files on DropBox or Google Drive with document based app ios

Tags: ios, ios11, swift4, uidocument, uidocumentbrowservc

I am working on an app which is a Document Based application ios 11 swift 4.

I am able to create new files on DropBox or Google Drive with the help of `importHandler` callback in delegate method of `UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate`.

I am able to edit those documents and save them in local Shared directory of DropBox or Google Drive.
But files doesn't synced with respective cloud consoles.

This works fine with iCloud.

Doesn't understand whats the issue with DropBox or Google Drive syncing process.

Please help me to find solution.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a way to make this work?